# How do i make 2 textViews apear in 1 row in listView?

Tags: java, android-listview

I want to make a contacts app without db with 2 input fields (Name and Phone) and one button where when the button is pressed the 2 inputs are going inside a list view, i found a way to do it with 1 input (item) but i dont know how to do it with 2 (item and sub item).

Comment: You can support your question with some code that you have already tried. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a simple map:

```
public static Map<String, String> namePhoneMap;
static {
    namePhoneMap = new HashMap<>();
    namePhoneMap.put("John Doe", "333-555-555");
    namePhoneMap.put("Peter Parker", "343-343-343");
    namePhoneMap.put("Steve Jobs", "000-000-000");
}
```

You can access to the map:

```
//Get first contact by name  
System.out.println(namePhoneMap.get("John Doe"));
```

Or:

```
//Get all key+value
namePhoneMap.forEach((name, phone) ->System.out.println("Name : " + name + "; Phone : " + phone));

//Whole map
System.out.println(namePhoneMap);
```

**Single:**
333-555-555
**Key+Val:**
Name : Steve Jobs; Phone : 000-000-000
Name : John Doe; Phone : 333-555-555
Name : Peter Parker; Phone : 343-343-343
**All:**
{Steve Jobs=000-000-000, John Doe=333-555-555, Peter Parker=343-343-343}

Comment: But how do i make that work with user input? User gives input for name and phone and then pressed add and then its being added in the listView

Comment: Try to read about Spring, https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/, read this guide and i think you can ask most of your questions. If you don't want to use DB you can use spring JPA